# Short Story ID - Man, apparent weakling, impresses macho brothers of gf/fiancé via daring rescues/fights

Tags: identification-request

I'm trying to identify a short story I once read:

## Plot Summary

A man is either dating or engaged to a women. Her macho brothers observe his unimpressive appearance and judge him to be a weakling. They go on some sort of trip together to a tropical island (I believe) and in a series of incidents, the man proves he is much more capable than he appears. In one incident he rescues one of the brothers during a diving trip. In another incident, he fights a jaguar or leopard using some sort of martial art he later explains to the brothers. In the end, the brothers are suitably impressed and the conflict is resolved.

## Context

As I recall, this was one of 2 or 3 stories in a somewhat small book of short stories by the same author. It was a hardback, from a public library. I would have read it in the 90's.

## Language and Style

It was written in English, and not a translation. The story was not very modern, and the book was also not a newer book, so I believe it could be mid-1900s kind of timeframe, but I'm not certain.

## Other Details

There was another story in the same collection about some apocalyptic scenario, but I don't recall the details. The story was light reading (nothing very challenging). I can't recall if it had illustrations, but it was at least for young adults, if not adults.

When I asked ChatGPT this same question, it suggested:

1. The Short Happy Life of Francis Macomber (wrong)
2. The Most Dangerous Game (wrong)
3. [A fabricated story, title, and author] because it ran out of ideas and decided not to mention it made something up.